# Replacing char in string with something else [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, string, char

So I have this string:

```
`This-is-my-string`
```

what I want to get as output :

```
This is my string
```

those `hyphen's` should be replaced with `blank space`.

I have tried using `substr_replace()` with `implode` from PHP resourced , but that didn't yield any success!

Comment: `str_replace('-', ' ', $str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `str_replace`

```
echo str_replace('-', ' ', 'This-is-my-string');
```

> The **str_replace()** function replaces some characters with some
>   other characters in a string

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="This-is-my-string";
$replaced_str=str_replace('-', ' ', $str);
```